# JAXB unmarshalling same XML element but different childs

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have the following XML that need to unmarshal:

```
<data>
    <property>
        <name>Color</name>
        <value>Red</value>
        <value>Green</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>Size</name>
        <description>
            <num>10</num>
            <uom>cm</uom>
        </description>
    </property>
</data>
```

How can I unmarshal this into POJO DataModel?

Thanks.

Comment: example: https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/. very easily found using Google

Comment: No, it is not the case as in the link. Here each `property` have a `name` (which is shared) but have `value` or `description` - so these are two different objects

Answer (score 0):

Depends what approach you use. "up-bottom" or "bottom-up".

"up-bottom" means you have XSD where you define `value` and `description` elements as a `choice` or you can have just two optional elements `value` and `description` right in `property` element type.
In that case jaxb generates proper POJO for you.

"bottom-up" you have to do same in POJO first and provide in it jaxb annotations accordingly.

BTW: If you are not sure how to do it "bottom-up", but want go with it - just make simple XSD, generate POJO and check how jaxb annotated it...